# Is there a way to automatically delete the checkpoint folder after EMR job completes?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I create and use checkpoints in my pyspark code.
Since I work with very large data frames they tend to balloon in size over time.
Is there a way to delete the checkpoint folder after the job is complete?

For example like in the pseudocode below:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("s3://path/Checkpoint_Folder")

df=spark.read.parquet("s3://path")
df2=df1. #Do stuff
df2=df2.checkpoint(False)
# Do more stuff

df3.write.parquet("s3://path/output")
s3.delete_object("s3://path/Checkpoint_Folder")
```

Is this possible in pyspark?

Comment: Do you terminate your cluster on job completion? If so, a simple option is to checkpoint to HDFS on the cluster. This should also be faster than writing to S3.

Comment: No I dont terminate the cluster. However the nodes, do get scaled-down and decommissioned, but the EMR cluster keeps running.

Answer (score 1):

From my [research](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/) and experimentation with Spark Checkpoint capability I understand the intended use case to be preventing a computationally expensive dataframe *within* a job from having to be re-computed in the event of a node failure.

Checkpointing breaks the lineage of a dataframe, preventing it from going all the way back to the input datasets. Instead the dataframe is loaded from reliable storage in the event of node failure. Although an S3 path can be given, the default filesystem [is cluster HDFS](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.setCheckpointDir.html?highlight=setcheckpointdir), a hint to the intended use.

A further hint that the checkpoint is not intended to persist beyond the job that created it is that there is no public API provided to read the checkpoint. Rather, reading is handled internally by Spark in the event of node failure.

Given the above and that typically clusters are transient, it makes sense that the Spark API does not provide for checkpoint deletion, instead the checkpoint is deleted when the cluster terminates.

Comment: Understood. I guess my use case is special since I run a very large job with for loops and require checkpoints for exactly what you mentioned. However, those checkpoints become redundant once the job is over. I guess I will put in place a life cycle policy for the checkpoint folder in my s3 bucket. Hopefully, that will delete the folder once a day or so.

Comment: Great. Please do up-vote if my answer helped you decide on a course of action.